# Error rendering a Simple.tag on template - Django

Tags: python, django

I've create a simple.tag on extratags.py which checks if the user is an attendant of the post event.

**extra_tags.py**

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_attendent_user(post_id, user_id):
    return Attending.objects.filter(post__id=post_id, attendant__id=user_id).exists()
```

If I render this **{% get_attendent_user post.id user.id %}** on the template is working but, the idea is to play with an IF condition there.

So if I render this on the template:

```
{% if get_attendent_user post.id user.id is False %}
<p>ok</p>
{% else %}
<p>Not requested</p>
{% endif %}
```

is giving me the error: **Unused 'post.id' at end of if expression.**

How can I correctly render this on the template?

Thanks!!

Comment: This is not how a template tag works, the idea of a template tag is that it works with `{% get_attendent_user ... %}`, not in a `{% if ... %}` template tag.

Comment: Hi Willem! Sorry, im kinda new to django... So its better to make this on views.py or how can I resolve this?

Comment: I would recommend to implement Models related logic on your specific view function

Comment: Could you please show me how?

Comment: you should check it in `view.py` and send variable with `True` or `False` to template

Comment: Hi @furas ! Could you please show me how is done?

Comment: there is nothing to show - run `Attending.objects.filter(...)` in `view.py`  and result send to template.

Comment: The problem here @furas is the template, its a listview and I should pass it through a context... and I dont know how to get the post_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically to put an IF inside that I modify the code in extra_tags.py

```
@register.filter
def get_attendent_user(value, arg):
    return Attending.objects.filter(post__id=value, attendant__id=arg).exists()
```

and then in the template

```
{% if post.id|get_attendent_user:user.id == False %}
 Doesn't exists
{% else %}
  Exists
{% endif %}
```